# How to delete dynamic images using react native?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

> In my scenario i am displaying array of images  with delete icon . I
>   need to delete the image while click on delete icon.How to acheieve
>   this using react native
>
> here is the sample code.

```
var image=["uri1","uri2","uri3"] //image url
var GetImageField = React.createClass({
  deleteImage:function(){
       this._imageDelete.setNativeProps({height: 0});
    },
render:function() {
      var self =this;

   return (<View> 
           {
             image.map(function(val){
              return (
                <Image source={val} style={styles.uploadImage} ref={component => self._imageDelete = component}>
                     <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#ffa456" onPress={self.deleteImage} style={{backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
                           <Text style={styles.deleteImage} >delete</Text>
                     </TouchableHighlight>
                </Image>)
              })
          }
          </View>)
}
```

Using setNativeProps  i can able to delete first selected image only.But i need to delete multiple images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way of handling this kind of things in React is by using the component state. Those images should be the initial state and when you remove them from the state, React will update the component to reflect the change:

```js
var GetImageField = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
 return {
   images: ["uri1", "uri2", "uri3"]
 }
},

deleteImage: function(val) {
 this.setState({
    images: this.state.images.filter(function(img){
      return img !== val
    })
 });
},

render: function() {
  var self = this;
  return ( < View >

      {
        this.state.images.map(function(val) {
         return ( < Image source = {val}
            style = {styles.uploadImage}
            ref = {component => self._imageDelete = component} >
            < TouchableHighlight underlayColor = "#ffa456"
            onPress = {self.deleteImage.bind(self, val)}
            style = {{ backgroundColor: '#fff'}} >
               < Text style = {styles.deleteImage} > delete < /Text>
            </TouchableHighlight >
            < /Image>)
         })
          }

      </View > )
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me for another more question regarding react native ,the question id is 33819424.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
 this.setState({
          arrayholder: this.state.arrayholder.filter(function(img){
            return img !== key
          })
  });
```

Comment: That's in accepted answer (you have `arrayholder` instead of `images`)